# Functional Sets / Apply method

Tags: scala

I have just started learning scala from the Coursera course by Martin Odesky. I am really struggling at the functional sets problem. The thing I am not able to catch is the union method-

```
object Functionalset {
  type Set = Int => Boolean
  def singletonSet(element: Int): Set = i => element == i
  def union(a: Set, b: Set): Set = i => a(i) || b(i)

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    print(singletonSet(2)(4));
  }
}
```

In the union method I am essentially returning a function that takes an `Int i` and calls `a(i) || b(i)` to check whether `i` is in the set or not. The `apply` method is not defined anywhere. What does the `a(i)` do? Does it call the `singletonSet(element:Int):Set`? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the a(i) do? Does it call the `singletonSet(element: Int)`

No, there is no relationship between the two methods. `a(i)` in this particular case is simply the invocation of the function `a`, which is a function from `Int` to `Boolean`.

---

`a` is a of type `Set`, which is a *type alias* for a function from `Int` to `Boolean` (`Int => Boolean` with Scala syntax sugar).

Think of it like this:

```
def union(a: Int => Boolean, b: Int => Boolean): Int => Boolean = i => a(i) || b(i)
```

Since `a` is a function of type `Function1[Int, Boolean]`, and so is `b`, calling `a(i)` is simply invoking the function with the passed value of `i`. Now, what may be confusing is the notation of:

```
i => a(i) || b(i)
```

Since `union` itself returns a *function*, it needs a *placeholder* for any future `Int` which may be passed in, this happens when you call `singletonSet(2)(4)`, if we desugarize it a little, you have:

```
val intermidiateFunction: Int => Boolean = singletonSet(2)
val result: Boolean = intermidiateFunction(4)
```

Think of it as a two step invocation of a method, when you do the first invocation, you get back *another function*, and only when you call it the second time, you get back the result of the generated function.

---

Let's invoke `union` and see what happens:

```
scala> union(i => i < 3, i => i > 1)
res6: Set = <function1>

scala> val result = union(i => i < 3, i => i > 1)
result: Set = <function1>

scala> result(1)
res7: Boolean = true
```

`union` requires us to pass in two functions, so we create these simplified functions that check whether an `Int` is smaller than 3 or bigger than 1. The result of the first invocation is itself a function. When we'll now pass in an `Int` to the result, for example: `result(1)`, we will check `1 < 3 || 1 > 1`, which is equivalent to `a(i) || b(i)`, where `a` is the first function, and `b` is the second.

Answer (score 1):

In this lab, a set is defined as its [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). 
This translates into:

```
type Set = Int => Boolean
```

Which means that a `Set` is simply a function taking an `Int` and returning a `Boolean` (this is the characteristic function of the Set, an oracle which tells whether a given integer is in the set or not).

Your variable `a`, being a `Set`, is a function `Int => Boolean`, so `a(i)` is well-defined if `i` is an `Int`.

The characteristic function of a union of two sets is a function which returns true if its argument is in one of the two sets, false otherwise.